# Using Node.js and I want to code a welcome bot for my server

Tags: node.js, macos, discord, bots

I'm working in MacOS with node.js and I have a bot that sends messages in a channel but I want to get rid of MEE6 and only use my bot. So I want to add a welcome action when people join my server. I've looked on google for coding examples but none of the examples work with the current node.js build. I would like to send a welcome message in a dedicated channel. I want the bot to use the user's username in the message and give a message when someone joins and when someone leaves. Here is my current code.

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');


// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });


// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {

  client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('1010768161349587035').send(`**Welcome to the discord server, <@${guildMember.user.id}>!**`);
});

const randomMsg = ['message 1', 'message 2', 'message 3']

const random = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const sendRandomMsg = () => {

    client.channels.cache.get('1006941719666905089').send(randomMsg[random(0, randomMsg.length - 1)]);
}

setInterval(function(){ sendRandomMsg() }, 1000 * 60 );

});
console.log('(。··)_且');

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

I tried adding more intents from this example:

```
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS //also enable in discord developer portal
    ] 
})
```

But when I add these intents as they are coded, it returns an error saying "Intents" isn't defined. I added SERVER MEMBERS INTENT on the discord developer portal. But when I join the server with my alt account nothing happens in the welcome channel. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this need a discord tag?

Comment: @wyck Sorry I forgot but I just edited it.

Comment: You have `Intents` never declared.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from a bot of mine. Hope this helps! :D

[ keep in mind you'll need to adjust some things to make it work how you want :) ]

```
// Import Discord.js
const {
    Client,
    Collection,
    GatewayIntentBits,
    Partials
} = require('discord.js');

// I like importing the intents and partials this way, just to make things a little more visible. But the main things we're importing here are the Guild, and GuildMembers [PLURAL]
const { Guilds, GuildMembers, MessageContent, GuildMessages } = GatewayIntentBits;

// And here, we're importing the GuildMember [SINGULAR] for our Partials
const { User, Message, Channel, GuildMember } = Partials;

// Create Discord Client
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Guilds,
        GuildMembers, // IMPORTANT
        GuildMessages,
        MessageContent,
    ],
    partials: [
        User,
        Channel,
        Message,
        GuildMember, // IMPORTANT
    ],
});

// Adding the GuildMembers to our intents, and GuildMember to our partials allows for us to receive the info we need for a welcome message; ei. when a member joins

// And lastly, when a member joins. I noticed you had the event inside your ready event, but it needs to be outside the ready so be sure to double check that :)
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (guildMember) => {
    console.log(guildMember); // View the member data
    
    await guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('ChannelID').send(`Hello, World! ${guildMember.user.username + "#" + guildMember.user.discriminator}`);
});

// The goodbye message is pretty much the exact same, but we'll use the guildMemberRemove event
your ready event, but it needs to be outside the ready so be sure to double check that :)
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async (guildMember) => {
    console.log(guildMember); // View the member data
        
    await guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('ChannelID').send(`Goodbye, World! ${guildMember.user.username + "#" + guildMember.user.discriminator}`);
});

// Add bot login, ready event, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I still had some kinks to work out to make it this work but it is now greeting and farewelling members that move in the server. I aprreci

Comment: Ayy! Glad i could be of help! :D

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with an embedded message because it is cleaner and gives more writing and linking options. Thank you so much @baeonette for laying out the code in a different way so I could understand what I am doing a little better. Here is the error free code:

```
// Import Discord.js
const {
    Client,
    Collection,
    GatewayIntentBits,
    Partials,
    EmbedBuilder
} = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// I like importing the intents and partials this way, just to make things a little more visible. 
// But the main things we're importing here are the Guild, and GuildMembers [PLURAL]
const { Guilds, GuildMembers, MessageContent, GuildMessages } = GatewayIntentBits;

// And here, we're importing the GuildMember [SINGULAR] for our Partials
const { User, Message, Channel, GuildMember } = Partials;

// Create Discord Client
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Guilds,
        GuildMembers, // IMPORTANT
        GuildMessages,
        MessageContent,
    ],
    partials: [
        User,
        Channel,
        Message,
        GuildMember, // IMPORTANT
    ],
});

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {

// Adding the GuildMembers to our intents, and GuildMember to our partials allows for us to 
// receive the info we need for a welcome message; ei. when a member joins

// And lastly, when a member joins. I noticed you had the event inside your ready event, 
// but it needs to be outside the ready so be sure to double check that :)

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (GuildMember) => {
console.log(GuildMember); // View the member data

});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    const embed7 = new EmbedBuilder()

    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('A title')
    .setURL('https://paypal.me/tripbranch')
    .setAuthor({name: `${guildMember.user.username}`, iconURL: guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}), url: 'https://paypal.me/tripbranch'})
    .setThumbnail(`A picture.PNG`)
    .setDescription('A description')
    .setImage(`A picture.PNG`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'A footer', iconURL: `A picture.PNG` });
   
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('Channel ID here').send({embeds: [embed7]})
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', async (GuildMember) => {
    console.log(GuildMember); // View the member data
    
    });

client.on('guildMemberRemove', guildMember =>{
    const embed8 = new EmbedBuilder()

    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('A title')
    .setURL('https://paypal.me/tripbranch')
    .setAuthor({name: `${guildMember.user.username}`, iconURL: guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}), url: 'https://paypal.me/tripbranch'})
    .setThumbnail(`A picture.PNG`)
    .setDescription('A description')
    .setImage(`A picture.PNG`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'A footer', iconURL: `A picture.PNG` });
   
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('Channel ID here').send({embeds: [embed8]})
});

            console.log('ready');

});        

            // Login to Discord with your client's token
            client.login(token);
```

[image: A picture of the embedded message for someone joining. The embedding option allows you to link the words to a donation page as well.]